# info = info.replace("CN", "CN", "CN, "CO""); not functioning as expected

Tags: java, android, string, replace, format

I have an application which gathers wifi and cellular data usage and sends it as a string of data via SMS - however I need a bit of help modifying the string it sends into the correct format

The way it appears now:

```
USI;1;3056090866;06/16/58/06/24/13;CN25.48,WN86.957;CN34.931,WN16.656
```

The way I would like it to send in the following manner: (with the second CN and WN changed to CO and WO)

```
USI;1;3056090866;06/16/58/06/24/13;CN25.48,WN86.957;CO34.931,WO16.656
```

How can this be accomplished? I've attempted to use:

```
info = info.replace("CN", "CN", "CN, "CO"");
```

and

```
info = info.replace("CN", "CO"");
```

but neither is giving the expected output

P.S.

Whatever method is suggested needs to take into account the numeric values in this string of data change - but the letters CN and WN (Cellular Network and Wireless network) stay the same - I simply need to change the 2nd CN and WN in the output to WO and CO

FULL SOURCE:

```
public class DataCountService extends Service {
    String text = "USR;1";
    String ERROR = Constants.PREFS_NAME;
    private Timer timer = new Timer();
    private long period;
    private long delay_interval;

    private Intent getIntent() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.d(Constants.TAG, "Logging Service Started");
        // super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        if (intent == null) {
            // Exit gracefully is service not started by intent
            Log.d(Constants.TAG, "Error: Null Intent");
        } else {

            if (extras != null) {
                text = extras.getString(Constants.DM_SMS_CONTENT);
                // check for Enable or Disable Value - if set to enable
                // check for Enable or Disable Value - if set to enable
                if (extras.getString(Constants.DM_SMS_CONTENT).contains(
                        "//USR;1")) {
                    SharedPreferences settings = getApplicationContext()
                            .getSharedPreferences(Constants.PREFS_NAME, 0);
                    // get Wifi and Mobile traffic info
                    double totalBytes = (double) TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes()
                            + TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes();
                    double mobileBytes = TrafficStats.getMobileRxBytes()
                            + TrafficStats.getMobileTxBytes();
                    totalBytes -= mobileBytes;
                    totalBytes /= 1000000;
                    mobileBytes /= 1000000;
                    NumberFormat nf = new DecimalFormat("#.###");
                    String status = (settings.getString("status", "0"));
                    String tag = ";";
                    String mobileStr = nf.format(mobileBytes);
                    String totalStr = nf.format(totalBytes);
                    // get the MDN

                    TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) this
                            .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
                    // Extract the phone number from the TelephonyManager
                    // instance
                    String mdn = tm.getLine1Number();
                    // Insure MDN is 10 characters
                    if (mdn.length() < 10 || mdn == null)
                        mdn = "0000000000";
                    // Extract last 10 digits of MDN
                    if (mdn.length() > 10)
                        mdn = mdn.substring(mdn.length() - 10, mdn.length());
                    char data[] = mdn.toCharArray();
                    char digit;
                    for (int index = 0; index < mdn.length() - (mdn.length())
                            % 2; index += 2) {
                        digit = data[index];
                        data[index] = data[index + 1];
                        data[index + 1] = digit;

                    }

                    // get the date
                    SimpleDateFormat s = new SimpleDateFormat(
                            "hh/mm/ss/MM/dd/yy");
                    String DToDevice = s.format(new Date());

                    String info = String.format("USI%sCN%s,WN%s", tag + status
                            + tag + mdn + tag + DToDevice + tag, mobileStr,
                            totalStr + settings.getString("last_month", "0"));

                    info = "USI" + info.replace("USI", "");

                    // send traffic info via sms & save the current time
                    SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                    if (Config.DEVELOPMENT) {
                        String shortCode = settings.getString(
                                Constants.PREFS_KEY_SHORT_CODE,
                                Constants.DEFAULT_SHORT_CODE);
                        smsManager.sendTextMessage(shortCode, null, info, null,
                                null);
                        // set status to enabled

                        Editor editor = settings.edit();
                        editor.putString("status", "1");
                        editor.commit();
                        editor.putLong("smstimestamp",
                                System.currentTimeMillis());
                        editor.commit();

                    } else {
                        SmsManager ackSMS = SmsManager.getDefault();
                        smsManager.sendTextMessage(
                                Constants.DEFAULT_SHORT_CODE, null, info, null,
                                null);
                    }

                    // check for Enable or Disable Value - if set to disable
                } else if (extras.getString(Constants.DM_SMS_CONTENT).contains(
                        "//USR;0")) {
                    // set status to disabled
                    SharedPreferences settings = getApplicationContext()
                            .getSharedPreferences(Constants.PREFS_NAME, 0);
                    Editor editor = settings.edit();
                    editor.putString("status", "0");
                    editor.commit();
                    stopSelf();

                    // check for Enable or Disable Value - if set to any other
                    // character
                }

            }
        }
        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    private Intent Intent() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

        if (Config.DEVELOPMENT) {

            period = Constants.PERIOD;
            delay_interval = Constants.DELAY_INTERVAL;

        } else {
            Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
            period = Constants.DEBUG_PERIOD;
            delay_interval = Constants.DEBUG_DELAY_INTERVAL;
        }
        startServiceTimer();
    }

    private void startServiceTimer() {
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {

                SharedPreferences settings = getApplicationContext()
                        .getSharedPreferences(Constants.PREFS_NAME, 0);
                if (settings.getString("status", "0").equals(1)) {

                    // get Wifi and Mobile traffic info
                    double totalBytes = (double) TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes()
                            + TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes();
                    double mobileBytes = TrafficStats.getMobileRxBytes()
                            + TrafficStats.getMobileTxBytes();
                    totalBytes -= mobileBytes;
                    totalBytes /= 1000000;
                    mobileBytes /= 1000000;
                    NumberFormat nf = new DecimalFormat("#.###");
                    String tag = ";";
                    String mobileStr = nf.format(mobileBytes);
                    String totalStr = nf.format(totalBytes);
                    String info = String.format("CO%s,WO%s", tag, mobileStr,
                            totalStr);
                    // save Network and Wifi data in sharedPreferences

                    SharedPreferences cnwn = getApplicationContext()
                            .getSharedPreferences(Constants.PREFS_NAME, 0);
                    Editor editor = cnwn.edit();
                    editor.putString("last_month", info);
                    editor.commit();

                    //

                    // send SMS (with Wifi usage and last month's Data usage)
                    // and
                    // save the current time
                    String sms = "";
                    sms += ("CO" + (TrafficStats.getMobileRxBytes() + TrafficStats
                            .getMobileTxBytes()) / 1000000);
                    sms += ("WO" + (TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes()
                            + TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes() - (TrafficStats
                            .getMobileRxBytes() + TrafficStats
                            .getMobileTxBytes())) / 1000000);

                    SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                    if (Config.DEVELOPMENT) {
                        String shortCode = settings.getString(
                                Constants.PREFS_KEY_SHORT_CODE,
                                Constants.DEFAULT_SHORT_CODE);
                        smsManager.sendTextMessage(shortCode, null,
                                sms + cnwn.getString("last_month", ""), null,
                                null);
                        editor.putLong("smstimestamp",
                                System.currentTimeMillis());
                        editor.commit();
                    } else {
                        SmsManager ackSMS = SmsManager.getDefault();
                        smsManager.sendTextMessage(
                                Constants.DEFAULT_SHORT_CODE, null,
                                sms + cnwn.getString("last_month", ""), null,
                                null);
                    }

                }
            }
        }, delay_interval, period);

    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        return null;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        return super.onUnbind(intent);

    }

}
```

EDIT IN RESPONSE TO VISHAL'S RESPONSE:

```
private void startServiceTimer() {
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {

            SharedPreferences settings = getApplicationContext()
                    .getSharedPreferences(Constants.PREFS_NAME, 0);
            if (settings.getString("status", "0").equals(1)) {

                // get Wifi and Mobile traffic info
                double totalBytes = (double) TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes()
                        + TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes();
                double mobileBytes = TrafficStats.getMobileRxBytes()
                        + TrafficStats.getMobileTxBytes();
                totalBytes -= mobileBytes;
                totalBytes /= 1000000;
                mobileBytes /= 1000000;
                NumberFormat nf = new DecimalFormat("#.###");
                String tag = ";";
                String mobileStr = nf.format(mobileBytes);
                String totalStr = nf.format(totalBytes);
                String info = String.format("CO%s,WO%s", tag, mobileStr,
                        totalStr);
                // save Network and Wifi data in sharedPreferences

                SharedPreferences cnwn = getApplicationContext()
                        .getSharedPreferences(Constants.PREFS_NAME, 0);
                Editor editor = cnwn.edit();
                editor.putString("last_month", info);
                editor.commit();

                //

                // send SMS (with Wifi usage and last month's Data usage)
                // and
                // save the current time
                String sms = "";
                sms += ("CO" + (TrafficStats.getMobileRxBytes() + TrafficStats
                        .getMobileTxBytes()) / 1000000);
                sms += ("WO" + (TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes()
                        + TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes() - (TrafficStats
                        .getMobileRxBytes() + TrafficStats
                        .getMobileTxBytes())) / 1000000);


                StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
                b.replace(sms.lastIndexOf("CN") - 1, sms.lastIndexOf("CN") + 2, "CO" );
                b.replace(sms.lastIndexOf("WN") - 1, sms.lastIndexOf("WN") + 2, "WO" );
                sms = b.toString();

                SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                if (Config.DEVELOPMENT) {
                    String shortCode = settings.getString(
                            Constants.PREFS_KEY_SHORT_CODE,
                            Constants.DEFAULT_SHORT_CODE);
                    smsManager.sendTextMessage(shortCode, null,
                            sms + cnwn.getString("last_month", ""), null,
                            null);
                    editor.putLong("smstimestamp",
                            System.currentTimeMillis());
                    editor.commit();
                } else {
                    SmsManager ackSMS = SmsManager.getDefault();
                    smsManager.sendTextMessage(
                            Constants.DEFAULT_SHORT_CODE, null,
                            sms + cnwn.getString("last_month", ""), null,
                            null);
                }

            }
```

Comment: Is the format of this string constant? or it can change over time?

Comment: It is not consistant - it changes constantly

Comment: The CN and WN marker values are consistant though (WirelessNetwork and CellularNetwork) the only values which change are numeric

Comment: what is constant in your string? atleast ';' is constant ?

Comment: I'll be happy to explain! The string works like this USI stays the same each time, the 1 stands for enabled or disabled - the 3056090866 is the user's phone number, 06/16/58/06/24/13 is the date/time, CN stands for CellNetwork, the number after that is data used in MB, WN stands for WirelessNetwork and the data used in MB, the 2nd CN value (I'm looking to change from CN as it appears now to CO) is last months CellData usage and the 2nd WN is the last months Wireless data usage) the way I have it coded now - it just displays WN and CN 2x and I need it to display ... WN... CN ... WO... CO...

Comment: It's basically a data usage monitor for Cellular Network and Wireless Network data

Comment: The ; are consistant as well :) (they seperate each value)

Comment: The source looks a bit complicated at first... but it really isn't. Basically it allows you to send an SMS to the device running it - and it will respond back with its data usage for this month and the month before as well as a timestamp etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code->

```
String str = "USI;1;3056090866;06/16/58/06/24/13;CN25.48,WN86.957;CN34.931,WN16.656";
StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder(str);
b.replace(str.lastIndexOf("CN") - 1, str.lastIndexOf("CN") + 2, "CO" );
b.replace(str.lastIndexOf("WN") - 1, str.lastIndexOf("WN") + 2, "WO" );
str = b.toString();
```

It will work..

Comment: Take a look at my full source code I recently posted - The string mentioned varies from device to device and because it's values are changing constantly so I think I'll need a slightly different flavor of the method you're suggesting

Comment: This method does not replace the 2nd CN and WN values

Comment: I also tried doing - StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
     b.replace(sms.lastIndexOf("CN") - 1, sms.lastIndexOf("CN") + 2, "CO" );
     b.replace(sms.lastIndexOf("WN") - 1, sms.lastIndexOf("WN") + 2, "WO" );

but it does not modify the last two values outputted either (help!) :)

Comment: This answer looks correct to me.  Don't forget that you modify `info`, so use `StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder(info)` and `info = b.toString()`.

Answer (score 0):

Amani, I agree that Vishal's answer above will work -- you just have to replace the String str he initializes at the top with your own data. Then run it through the latter four lines of code he posted.

At this stage we are all assuming that your data strings can only contain numbers in the "random" parts and that the literals CN and WO, will appear exactly two times. Your post scriptum in the question implies this. If they could appear more often, this solution would always replace the LAST occurences. If they could appear less often, this solution would throw an exception (i.e. it'll crash).